# flattening list of lists in Scala with out using flatten method giving bad result

Tags: list, scala, scala-collections, flatten

I tried to flatten the list of lists using the below code. When I put it on paper, it should work but I think I misinterpreted or am ignorant of how lists work. Could any one tell me where i went wrong.

```
val a = List(List(1,2,3),List(4,5,6),List(7,8,9))

def flatten(xss : List[List[Any]]) : List[Any] = {
  def flat(xs : List[Any]) : List[Any] = xs match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case head :: Nil=> head :: Nil
    case head :: tail => head :: flat(tail)
  }
  xss match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case head :: Nil => flat(head)
    case head :: tail => flat(head) :: flatten(tail)
  }
}

flatten(a)
```

Comment: I think you need to take another thinking session about what flattening a list means, a good trick i tend to use is to express it in words because there often is a functional implementation that matches that pretty good.

Comment: Have you thought of using the built in flatMap function?

Comment: I should implement flatten function without using flatten method. Even shouldn't use :::

Comment: @johanandren . I am sure of what flattening the list means and am more worried about how to implement the functionality in Scala for which I wrote a function which process the inner lists through flat function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually pattern match deep into the structure:

```
def flatten[T](xss: List[List[T]]): List[T] = xss match {
   case Nil => Nil
   case Nil :: tail => flatten(tail)
   case (innerHead :: innerTail) :: tail => innerHead :: flatten(innerTail :: tail)
}
```

Comment: It's very efficient way of performing the job. Could you also look into my code and tell me where it went wrong. Also from the code, it does make difference(error) when I replace the second case with ` head :: Nil =>  flatten(head)`. What different does it make for the last value in the list anyways.

Comment: I came to know that head returns the primitive type where as the tail returns a List. Type mismatch is one problem that prevent me to execute some other approaches.

Comment: @Ram_TU Yes, the types gave the error away. For `List[T]` the left hand side of `::` has type `T` and the right hand side has type `List[T]`. In your original version you have `case head :: tail => flat(head) :: flatten(tail)` but the return type of `flat(head)` was a list not a single item.

Answer (score 1):

Your `flat` function just recreates its argument list so it can be dropped.

You simply need to concatenate the inside lists, using `:::`:

```
def flatten(xss : List[List[_]]): List[Any] = xss match {
  case Nil => Nil
  case head :: tail => head ::: flatten(tail)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made two minor changes to your example to get it working.  The first was to use a generic (not the problem, but clears up the code a bit).  The second was to use `:::` instead of `::` in the case where the input list has more than one item.  The `::` method prepends a single item to a List which is the type of items in the list.  The `:::` concatenates two lists together.  Using a type of `List[Any]`, you were not able to see that issue.  But once I changed the type to `T`, it was pretty clear where the issue was.

```
def flatten[T](xss : List[List[T]]) : List[T] = {
  def flat(xs : List[T]) : List[T] = xs match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case head :: Nil=> head :: Nil
    case head :: tail => head :: flat(tail)
  }
  xss match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case head :: Nil => flat(head)
    case head :: tail => flat(head) ::: flatten(tail)
  }
}
```

Comment: I should implement flatten function without using flatten method. Even shouldn't use :::